# Drag and Drop playlist from the sidebar onto the application view

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to drag and drop playlists from the side-bar onto my application window. I got it working to accept drops on my app's name in the app list, but that's not what I need right now.

Is there a way to enable my view to accept playlists dragged on it?

```
models.application.addEventListener("dropped", function() {
  console.log(models.application.dropped)
})
```

And in my manifest.json I have

```
"AcceptedViewDropTypes": [
    "playlist"
],

"AcceptedLinkTypes": [
    "playlist"
],
```

This setup triggers the console log only if I drop on my app's name.

Comment: I've solved the issue by coming up with a different UX thus not needing d&d anymore. Still, I'm interested in the solution and will try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of drag & drop for a Playlist in the [Spotify Apps Tutorial](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial), called [Dragging and dropping content into an app](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/getting-started/drag-drop.html).

The way it works is like regular drag & drop, listening to events such as dragstart or drop.

Comment: Looks like a winner, will try it out tomorrow. I wonder how this didn't pop up with a day of googling... Thanks!

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't work :( Even used the code they provided, and still no. :(

Comment: I don't want to offend you in some way. But I think you doing something wrong. It works! Maybe there is just a little error. Try it again ;)
Btw JMPerez is the author of this github repository :D

Comment: @meza I've tried it again, in this case isolating that single example, and it does seem to work for me. Maybe you could upload your app to Github so I can clone it and have a look at it.

Comment: There's obviously something I'm missing, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: @JMPerez Here's a screencast of the code on my box from the repo. (The manifest file is set up as stated) meza.s3.amazonaws.com/tmp/spotydrag.mov Could this be a platform (osx) issue?

Comment: @meza, great idea to share screencast. It seems like you're missing some assets though, this is not what the tutorial should look like (e.g. http://i.imgur.com/goR5tVV.png?1). Did you clone the tutorial correctly? Are you on the master branch, with no changes to the tutorial?

Comment: @meza Are you actually running the Javascript code? Take into account that the tutorial app does a smart dynamic evaluation of the code snippets. You need to make sure that the Javascript code is executed.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem.

Having

  "AcceptedViewDropTypes": [
    "playlist"
  ],

in my manifest file stopped it from working.
Thanks for the help everyone!